# Other than ActiveMQ JMS providers with OpenEJB - possibly external

Tags: java, jms, messaging, activemq-classic, openejb

We are in the process of testing OpenEJB solution that embeds ActiveMQ 4.1.1. We observe various problems with messaging (bugs, performance, stability). One option is to upgrade to just released OpenEJB 3.1.3 that comes with later ActiveMQ 5.1.3. But I am trying to evaluate other options in case these problems won't go away.

Is it possible to plug different JMS provider with OpenEJB 3.1.x? There is [configuration for **external** ActiveMQ Broker](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html). Would it work with non-ActiveMQ Broker, e.g. JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap out the JMS provider by plugging in a new Resource Adapter implementation, then declare that in your openejb.xml.  Here's an [email from a user](http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Outbound-resource-injection-in-an-ejb-tp1013402p1129356.html) who replaced ActiveMQ with Tibco.  Start with an empty openejb.xml file to be sure you don't have ActiveMQ stuff hanging around.

JBoss probably has a Resource Adapter for thier JMS provider, so you wouldn't need to use the GenericJMSRA like they guy did in that email.  You'd just need to create a service-jar.xml for the JBoss JMS RA as that user did for the GenericJMSRA.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know that it's possible. I wish you have had some documentation for this type of integration in OpenEJB with references. I promise that if I get to implement this in our app I'll donate you the documentation from our internal wiki that we always maintain.

Comment: Just for clarification: is it for embedded JMS provider or external one? The Tibco example must be external provider, right?

Comment: @grigory  Right, external.  A Resource Adapter is sort of like a JDBC driver.  Usually it connects to something that's external, but there are some implementations that support embedding (like ActiveMQ).  In regards to documentation, what we have is mostly user contributed.  If you sign up for an account here and email me your id, I can set you up as an author https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/dashboard.action

Comment: great, will do. One more question though. Is there any example of activemq.xml in 3.1.3 (for ActiveMQ 5.3.x)?

Comment: We have a unit test for it, but no example.  Happy to accept one.  Primary thing you need is the xbean-spring and dependent jars.  I'll see if I can pull Andy Gumbrecht over (another user/committer), he's been doing all the ActiveMQ work as of late.